# A screencasting tool for streaming programming tutorial?

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I am asked to teach a programming class *in a live video stream* over the web.

Everything seems to go well, but I've just found out that stream quality will be limited to

1. Resolution: below (1024px * 768px)
2. Bitrate: below (1000 kbps)

Therefore, using my IDE in full screen is not a choice because the code will not be visible. I could change my monitor's resolution, but that'd be my last approach.

I just need a feature that I can actively switch the view from one code block to other code block.

Is there any tool that suits my needs? (BTW. I use IntelliJ in Windows 7)

Comment: In my understanding "record and live stream" is somewhat different from "record to disk" ...

Comment: It is better if you keep the video recorded already with editing then in live session can play and explain it. So you can do all the editing on advance.

Comment: @Nish Usually, the nature of live stream classes are similar to [webinar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_conferencing)(I mean more like a seminar). I'm probably going to use all the time as a Q&A session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would check out [XSplit](https://www.xsplit.com/).

It will give you the ability to:

- limit your output bitrate
- limit how much of the screen you want to broadcast
- set up different 'Output Shots' so you can select which code block you want to output
- create a local recording of your output

Answer (score 5):

[Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com/)
Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for recording and live streaming. Source code is available to everyone to contribute and improve. Both 32 and 64 bit versions are available and it's completely free!

Download OBS from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/5793110/50e97e00-9919-11e3-8ca2-323d9d0bc1f8.exe?response-content-disposition=attachment;%20filename=OBS_0_612b_Installer.exe&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1394007663&Signature=oS7rTzzPZdaXdDPi6bkycjhtCwc=)

[FFsplit](http://www.ffsplit.com/)
A freeware application that lets users stream high quality content similar to XSplit Broadcaster and Flash Media Live Encoder.

Download FFsplit from [here](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/taqattack/ffsplit-public/downloads/FFsplit-07023-Full.exe)

**Personally** I advise you to use OBS. It's a great tool and consider one of the best live streaming software and has same and more options of `xsplit`