# Screen recording for programming course screencasts

Tags: gratis, screen-recording

I need a software to record my screen for screencasts, i.e. programming courses.

**License:**
The focus is open-source, but gratis is also accepted.

**OS:**
I asked for open-source because, normally, they are multi-platform. But the main focus is Ubuntu (Windows is also accepted).

---

**About the [possible duplicate](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/a-screencasting-tool-for-streaming-programming-tutorial):**
The referenced question focuses on **live-stream**. But I need to generate a video file from my recordings and **keep the video file**.

Comment: Please see: [Android screencast video recorder that doesn't need root](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3362/185) / [Android-Windows 8: What software do you recommend to screencast playing a game?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3421/185) / [A screencasting tool for streaming programming tutorial?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1934/185). Apart from that, your question lacks much information, e.g. what OS it should run on. [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: Much better. But "open-source" does not necessarily mean "cross-platform" – as much as "closed-source" doesn't mean "single-platform". As for the questions mentioned in my previous post: Please count them again, there's more than one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windows based open source free - Camstudio [link](http://camstudio.org/)

Java based open source free - JScreenRecorder [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jscreenrecorder/?source=directory)

You can try simple screen recorder for ubuntu specific

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder

sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

to uninstall :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge simplescreenrecorder
```

Comment: I think Java based screen recorder is OPEN source AND CROSS PLATFORM

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use Microsoft Screen Recorder for full screen captures. It produces very small files, but in WMV of course. Some people can't play WMV when you email the files (yes they are that small), but YouTube can import them.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx?pr=blog

For recording a browser tab (or fullscreen), I sometimes use Screncastify. It records in standard WEBM which is HTML5 compliant and it can automatically save to your Google Drive for sharing. It's a bit cumbersome to figure out the options and how to set it up as most Google software is, but it seems to work. The free version is only limited to 10m however.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

There is also Wink but that generates FLV files. They are very small and you can edit them and add annotations, but I favor the more common regular file formats for sharing. YouTube can't import FLV files (if I remember). You could probably transcode the file with VLC or FFMPEG, but I haven't tried.

http://www.debugmode.com/wink/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [RecordMyDesktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gtk-recordmydesktop/) on Ubuntu in the past, to create videos from Google-Earth "flights". It supports partial screen recording. Together with OpenShot, a video editor software, [this was the outcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znQFEDongqc).